# Why can CPRI links not be wireless?

Tags: digital-communications

I have been studying about CRAN and the CPRI links (fronhaul links) and have observed that CPRI links are always either fiber cable or some electrical interface. Why is this needed? Is it related to the latency, bandwidth and cost requirement of the CPRI standard?
Thanks

Comment: Perhaps some _references_ for what the various acronyms mean would help.

Comment: Im really sorry. Here are the references.

CRAN - Centralised Radio Access Networks        
China Mobile Research Institute, “C-RAN: The road towards green RAN”, 2011.


CPRI - Common Public Radio Interface
CPRI Specifications V4.2.0(2010-09-29), “Common Public Radio Interface (CPRI); Interface Specifications,”
2010